# How to Modify This ES6 Code so as to Insert a Breakpoint?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, apollostack

I'm learning ES6 syntax, as well as the latest Apollo libs. This `withData` code is adapted from the Githunt-React Apollo demo.

```
const withData = graphql(GETIMS_QUERY, {
    options: ({ params }) => ({
        variables: {
            "fromID": Meteor.userId(),
            "toID": `${params.toID}`,
        },
    }),
});
```

`params` doesn't seem to contain what I expect. I'd like to insert a breakpoint in order to examine the contents of `params`.  But if I add a breakpoint next to `options`, I find that `params` is undefined.

I guess I may need to add a breakpoint inside this code block in order to see the contents of `params`:

```
const withData = graphql(GETIMS_QUERY, {
    options: ({ params }) => ({
        //IS THERE A WAY TO ADD A BREAKPOINT IN HERE SOMEHOW?
        //MAYBE RETURN `VARIABLES` AS A FUNCTION RESULT?
        variables: {
            "fromID": Meteor.userId(),
            "toID": `${params.toID}`,
        },
    }),
});
```

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks in advance to all for any info.

Comment: Try adding the breakpoint in the next line, not at `options`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `console.log` (and you can add a breakpoint on that line) and return the object explicitly:

```
const withData = graphql(GETIMS_QUERY, {
    options: ({ params }) => {
        console.log(params);

        return {
          variables: {
            "fromID": Meteor.userId(),
            "toID": `${params.toID}`,
          },
        };
    },
});
```